# How to write this inequality in terms of Schur Complement?

Tags: linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

I know the basis about Schur-Complement. Anyway, while looking at this inequality to apply it in order to solve for $\lambda$ such that the the matrix is definite positive, I got a little bit confused because the lack of non inverse terms.

${ X }^{ T }\left( PA+{ A }^{ T }P \right) X<-\lambda { X }^{ T }AX$

May I... ?

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & { X } \\ { X }^{ T } & { \left( PA+{ A }^{ T }P+\lambda A \right)  }^{ -1 } \end{bmatrix}$

Or,

$\begin{bmatrix} { X }^{ T }\left( PA+{ A }^{ T }P+\lambda A \right) X & { P } \\ P & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Or even,

$\begin{bmatrix} { X }^{ T }\left( PA+{ A }^{ T }P \right) X & X \\ { X }^{ T } & -\lambda { A }^{ -1 } \end{bmatrix}$

I'm sorry if this is a silly or even stupid question, but i'm lost :( 
Any references, books, or examples that You could recommend me?

Comment: 1) Which matrix should be definite positive ? 2) What are the dimensions of your matrices ?

Comment: The only thing my professor gave us is A, a 3x3 matrix, and that $x^T·x=||x||^2$ :( A'm sorry if it's pretty ambiguous :( The mean objective to use S-Complement, is to use YALMIP over MATLAB to solve for $\lambda$; at least that's what I understood. If you need more information, please list it, and I will ask my professor if there is any missing information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $\lambda$ your only unknown because that is the only variable you want to solve for? If that is the case then your first equation is already a LMI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of using Schur's complements here.

In fact, looking for $\lambda$ satisfying inequality

$$X^T\left( PA+A^TP \right) X<-\lambda X^TAX\tag{1}$$

is the same as looking for the bounds of

$$\dfrac{X^TBX}{X^TAX} \ \ \text{where} \ \ B:=PA+A^TP \tag{2}$$

which is a classical issue :

If $A$ is positive-definite, consider a Cholesky decomposition $A=C^TC$, set $Y=CX$, transforming (2) into the Rayleigh quotient :

$$\dfrac{YC^{-T}BC^{-1}Y}{Y^TY} $$

which is known to take all values in interval $[\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$
where $\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}$ are the extreme eigenvalues of matrix $D:=C^{-T}BC^{-1}$.

Connected :

[Proof: Ratio of matrix traces and difference of traces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304738)

[Ratio of two quadratic vector forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1433761)